# when I execute the python manage.py runserver, CMD throws AttributeError:

Tags: python, django, xampp, mysql-python, attributeerror

I am new to Django! So I built a simple blog application using python/Django, MySQL as the back end using the XAMPP control panel. It was running as expected on http://localhost:8000. However, at the end of project when I added a Button functionality & restarted(python manage.py runserver) the server using the CMD. The CMD threw: AttributeError: module 'posts.views' has no attribute 'details'.

Your help wold be appreciated!

-Attached is the project on GitHub.

urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^details/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.details, name='details')
]
```

views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Posts

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
# return HttpResponse('HELLO FROM POSTS')

posts = Posts.objects.all()[:10]

context = {
   'title': 'Latest Posts',
   'posts': posts
}

return render(request, 'posts/index.html', context)

def details(request, id):
   post = Posts.object.get(id=id)

   context = {
       'post': post
   }

   return render(request, 'posts/details.html', context)
```

details.py file:

```
{% extends 'posts/layout.html' %}

{% block content%}
<h3 class="center-align red lighten-3">{{post.title}}</h3>
<div class = "card">
<div class="card-content">
    {{post.body}}
</div>
<div class="card-action">
    {{post.created_at}}
</div>
</div>
<a href="/posts" class="btn">Go Back</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Error stacktrace:

```
(py1) C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Google Drive\GitHub\Projects\djangoproject>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\ajmal .m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in 
_bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "c:\users\ajmal .m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", 
line 117, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in 
check
all_issues = self._run_checks(
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in 
_run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in 
run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in 
check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in 
check_resolver
return check_method()
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in 
url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in 
urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "c:\users\ajmal .m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, 
in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Google Drive\GitHub\Projects\djangoproject\djangoproject\urls.py", line 5, in 
<module>
url(r'^$', include('posts.urls')),
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "c:\users\ajmal .m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, 
in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Ajmal .M\Google Drive\GitHub\Projects\djangoproject\posts\urls.py", line 6, in 
<module>
url(r'^details/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.details, name='details')
AttributeError: module 'posts.views' has no attribute 'details'
```

[GitHub Link for the Project files](https://github.com/Alex-Moh/Google-Drive)

Comment: Likely the `urls.py` and the `views.py` are not in the same module (directory)?

Comment: They are - just reconfirmed!

Comment: Your GitHub link is broken and the indentation of your code needs fixing

Comment: If your details function view exists in any specific app then correct view.details as `from your_app import views as your_app_views` and `url(r'^details/(?P<id>\d+)/$', your_app_views.details, name='details')`

Answer (score 0):

You possibly want to add a View class in your `views.py`. Like this:

```py
from django.views import View
class Details(View):
    def get(request, id):
    post = Posts.object.get(id=id)

    context = {
        'post': post
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/details.html', context)
```

This might require changing your urls.py to:

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^details/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.details.as_view(), name='details')
]
```

(Note the `.as_view()`.)